# Notes and attachment in Winter'18 release

Tags: attachment, files, notes, winter18

In winter'18 Notes & Attachments related list will no longer have an Upload File button. 
In my application, I am inserting the attachment using apex code. I just want to confirm if we can still upload attachment using apex or not.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_files_add_related_list_to_page_layouts.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's you're seeing in the Release notes is a UI issue, not a functionality issue in terms of the platform for the attachments. You should still be able to create the custom functionality.

Comment: So I can upload attachment using Apex. But, I think I should now plan to move to files. Thanks @crmprogdev

Comment: That's correct, esp if you're planning to move to Lightning.

Comment: Is there a feature/function/code, which can work on conversion of Attachment to File whenever code/integration system create attachment?

Comment: @Ankuli Doug Ayers wrote some code that's available from his [Github repository](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files) to convert existing attachments to files as content. He wrote [this blog post](https://douglascayers.com/2015/10/10/salesforce-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Knowledge Article, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=New-Note-button-Notes-Attachments-related-list&language=en_US&type=1 which says that "Upload Files" button will remain available in the legacy Notes & Attachments related list.